# rvest: XPath and CSS does not work for The Weather Network

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

for practice, I am currently trying to scrape a website from the Weather Network for e.g. New York (https://www.theweathernetwork.com/us/weather/new-york/new-york). By now, I get along with X-Path and CSS alright, but I can't figure the correct ones out for this website. For now, I just want to scrape the very basic part in the table that says: "Sunny", "Chance of a shower", "Wet snow" etc.

I have so far tried:

```
library(rvest)

URL <- 'https://www.theweathernetwork.com/us/weather/new-york/new-york'
weather_html <- read_html(URL)

# Trying to use X-Path
forecast1 <- html_nodes(weather_html, xpath = "//*[@class = 'wxRow']/span") %>%
  html_text()

# Trying to use CSS Selector provided by Firefox Inspector Tool
forecast2 <- html_nodes(weather_html, "div.wxColumn:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(1)") %>%
  html_text()

# Trying to use the CSS Selector from CSS Selector Gadget
forecast3 <- html_nodes(weather_html, '.wx_description') %>%
  html_text()
```

None of these work and return empty lists/character strings.

The website itself appears to be scrapeable using rvest since it is working for another part of the website:

```
test <- html_nodes(weather_html, xpath = "//*[@class = 'wx-title']") %>%
  html_text()
```

which yields "Next 7 Days" as expected.

Sorry if this is a really dumb question and thanks for your help!

Comment: I used the *SelectorGadget* and selected some part, but it seems that the values are empty:  `weather_html %>% html_nodes(".secondary-obs") %>% html_text()`, although there're some text.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Just for clarification: Does this mean that I cannot scrape this particular website or do you know of a workaround?

Comment: For some reason it seems that the site is protected. You can ask for the API though. It's easier. Or you can use other [website](https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USNY0996:1:US). `weather_html <- read_html(URL)` and then `weather_html %>% html_nodes(".temp") %>% html_text()` to get temperature, for example.